# What Do I Need to Do to Change the Animation Direction on this Button?

Tags: css, animation

The client I am working for REALLY likes these buttons.
https://www.greenwichlibrary.org/

I've been pulling their code from the inspector to get started. I'm almost there, but my animation is going in the opposite direction and I do not know enough about CSS animations to pinpoint the problem. What I have so far is here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYXbJG

I'd like any help with just reversing the direction of the animation so that it matches the inspiration. After that, I can work on re-writing the code to fit my existing classes and to swap the SVG for an icon font. :)

```
<a href="#" class="button explore">Discover Here<span class="button-arrow"><img src="https://www.greenwichlibrary.org/wp-content/themes/greenwich-sage/assets/images/icons/button-arrow.svg"></span></a>
```

```
.explore {
    background-color: blue;
}

.button {
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 13px 62px 13px 18px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out !important;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out !important;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.button.explore::before {
    background-color: green;
}

.button::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 42px;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    -o-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button .button-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 42px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 42px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.button .button-arrow img {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.button.explore::after {
    background-color: green;
}

.button::after {
    content: '';
    height: 42px;
    padding: 14px 0 15px 16px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    width: 42px;
      transform-origin:left;
  transition:width 0.25s ease;
  z-index:-1;
}

.button:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}

.button:active, .button:focus, .button:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    outline: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

:active, :focus, :hover, :visited {
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: left:0 instead of right:0?

Comment: try changing .button:hover::after {width: 100%} to .button:hover::before {width: 100%;transform: scaleX(1)}. You aren't expanding the correct pseudo element upon mouseover.